# Tauberian operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a Banach space non reflexive and $T$ from $l_2(X)$ to $l_2(X)$ a bounded operator defined by:
$$T(x_n )=\frac{x_n }{n}.$$
We know that :
$$T^{**-1}(l_2(X))=\{x_n^{**} \in l_2(X^{**}) : \frac{x_n^{**}}{n} \in l_2 (X)\}.$$
To prove that $T$ is Tauberian, it suffices to prove that $T^{**−1}(l_2(X))\subset l_2(X)$. I.e., we will check that: $\sum \|x_n^{**}\|^{2} < \infty.$
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed as follows. Let $(x_n^{**})\in \ell_2(X^{**})$. Then
$$(x_n^{**})\in T^{**-1}(\ell_2(X))\Rightarrow T^{**}(x_n^{**})= 
(\frac{x_n^{**}}{n})\in \ell_2(X),$$ 
hence $(x_n^{**})\in \ell_2(X)$.

Comment: We have $\frac{x_n^{**}}{n} \in l_2(X) $, then $\sum|| \frac{x_n^{**}}{n}||^{2} < \infty $. Taking account that $\sum|| \frac{x_n^{**}}{n}||^{2} \leq \sum|| x_n^{**}||^{2}$, so perhaps $\sum|| x_n^{**}||^{2}=\infty$.

Comment: $(x_n^{**}/n)\in \ell_2(X)\Rightarrow x_n^{**}\in X$ for each $n$. Moreover   $(x_n^{**})\in \ell_2(X^{**})$ and  $x_n^{**}\in X$ for each $n$ implies $(x_n^{**})\in \ell_2(X)$.

Comment: Please, a nother quetion Mr. Gonzalez. If $(x_n ^{**}) \in l_2 (X^{**})$ and $(x_n^{**}) \in X$, then $(x_n ^{**}) \in l_2 (X^{**}) \cap X $. How to conclude that $(x_n ^{**}) \in l_2 (X)$.